# Docker - Volume not mounting latest files in container

Tags: linux, unix, ubuntu, docker, fig

## The Problem

When I start a new container in Docker, I want to mount a volume so that I get the latest updates to any files on my host machine and can work with them in my container. However, what I am finding is that Docker is mounting my volumes when I build the *image*. What I want instead is to mount the volumes when I create a new container.

Because I am using Docker to manage my development environment, this means that whenever I update a little piece of code, I have to rebuild my development environment Docker *image*, which takes usually around 20-30 mins. Obviously, this is not the functionality I want from Docker.

Here is what I am using to build my development environment container:

---

#### Dockerfile

```
# This docker file constructs an Ubuntu development environment and configures the compiler/libs needed
FROM ubuntu:latest

ADD . /gdms-rcon/liaison
WORKDIR /gdms-rcon/liaison

RUN rm -rf ./build
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y -f gcc g++ qtbase5-dev cmake mysql-client
```

---

#### fig.yml

```
liaison:
  build: ./liaison/
  command: /bin/bash
  volumes:
    - liaison:/gdms-rcon/liaison
  working_dir: /gdms-rcon/liaison
```

---

I also use a `fig.yml` file to make it easier to build.

To run, I use: `fig build`

To access my container to compile my source code, I use: `docker run -it <container_id>`

Maybe I'm doing something wrong with my commands? I don't use `fig up` because it won't give me an interactive shell, so I use `docker run -it <container_id>` instead. I chose to use `fig` so that it would mount my volumes automatically, but it isn't working as I would have hoped.

---

#### Here is an image to more clearly demonstrate my problem

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're not using `fig` to start the container, the `volumes` line in your `fig.yml` isn't doing anything useful.  If you need an interactive shell, `fig` is not really the tool for you.

Just `docker build` your image like normal, and then use the `-v` flag to `docker run` to mount the volume:

```
docker run -it -v <hostpath>:<containerpath> <imageid>
```

Comment: This is useful, but I figured out I had to use `fig run <service>` to get it to mount my volume in a new container. What your answer provides is almost exactly the functionality that `fig run` provides. Thank you!